Search in multiple Excel files (by values) containing same sheets and give information for range
I have several Excel files in a folder. Each contains the same Sheets, with similar data for companies.
These are data on medical examinations of employees and documents, both of which have expiration dates.
In addition to the expiration dates, in one of the adjacent columns there are Excel formulas that give the number of days remaining until expiration, and in the other the expiration status (<30 days and <15 days).
I created a separate Excel file where there are two tables in the sheet.
In one is the URL of the folder where the company files are located, and in the second table is the list of companies.
The second table serves as a list for selecting only one file.
In this particular Excel file, I created a UserForm that contains the following elements:

TextBox 'txtPDFolder' for typing the url location of the folder containing multiple Excel files for checking.
It is not mandatory that the ComboBox 'cboPDrustvo' is filled.
ComboBox 'cboPDrustvo' for company selection.
Optional if TextBox 'txtPDFolder' is filled.
Two CheckBoxes 'cbo15' and 'cbo30' for selecting the status "<15 DAYS" or "<30 DAYS".
TextBox 'txtBrojdana' for entering the maximum number of remaining days, for search.
TextBox 'txtDatumPer' to search for the expiration date.

Only one choice from options 3 or 4 or 5 is sufficient.
UserForm should serve to search option 3 or 4 or 5 in sheets named "O5 Zap", "O10 ZdravP", "O7 URS" or "O8 SZR" in one file (option 2) or files (option 1) with the name Company. When it finds the value from the selected option 3 or 4 or 5 in each of these sheets then it should create a report with a list of all the rows (within a certain range) in which the selected option is located.
I tried to create VBA code using ChatGPT. This code gives an error because it fails to find and open the company's Excel file or it gives an error because it fails to find a file with the extension .xlsm or it does not find the required option 3 or 4 or 5 in the rows.
In the VBA code there is a UserForm calendar for selecting dates.
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim status As String
    Dim remainingDays As Integer
    Dim expDate As Date
    Dim foundRows As String
    
    If Len(Trim(Me.txtPDFolder.Value)) > 0 Then
        folderPath = Me.txtPDFolder.Value
    ElseIf Me.cboPDrustvo.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        fileName = Me.cboPDrustvo.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Enter URL folder location or choose Company.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Me.chb15.Value And Me.chb30.Value Then
        status = "BOTH"
    ElseIf Me.chb15.Value Then
        status = "<15 DAYS"
    ElseIf Me.chb30.Value Then
        status = "<30 DAYS"
    End If
    
    If Len(Trim(Me.txtBrojdana.Value)) > 0 Then
        If Not IsNumeric(Me.txtBrojdana.Value) Then
            MsgBox "Broj dana mora biti numerička vrednost.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        Else
            remainingDays = CInt(Me.txtBrojdana.Value)
        End If
    End If
    
    If Me.txtDatumPer.Value <> "" Then
        expDatr = Me.txtDatumPer.Value
    End If
    
    foundRows = ""
    
    If Len(folderPath) > 0 Then
        fileName = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xlsm")
        If fileName = "" Then
            MsgBox "Nema fajlova sa ekstenzijom .xlsm u izabranom folderu.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Do While fileName <> ""
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & fileName)
            For Each ws In wb.Sheets
                Select Case ws.Name
                    Case "O5 Zap"
                        ProcessSheet ws, status, remainingDays, expDate, foundRows, "W", "V", "U", "L", "W"
                    Case "O10 ZdravP"
                        ProcessSheet ws, status, remainingDays, expDate, foundRows, "O", "N", "L", "A", "O"
                    Case "O7 URS"
                        ProcessSheet ws, status, remainingDays, expDate, foundRows, "P,U", "O,T", "M,R", "A", "U"
                    Case "O8 SZR"
                        ProcessSheet ws, status, remainingDays, expDate, foundRows, "I", "H", "F", "A", "I"
                End Select
            Next ws
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            fileName = Dir
        Loop
    ElseIf Len(fileName) > 0 Then
        If Right(fileName, 5) <> ".xlsm" Then
            fileName = fileName & ".xlsm"
        End If
        
        If Dir(nazivFajla) = "" Then
            MsgBox "Fajl '" & fileName & "' ne postoji.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Nije moguće otvoriti fajl '" & fileName & "'.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            Select Case ws.Name
                Case "O5 Zap"
                    ProcessSheet ws, status, remainingDays, expDate, foundRows, "W", "V", "U", "L", "W"
                Case "O10 ZdravP"
                    ProcessSheet ws, status, remainingDays, expDate, foundRows, "O", "N", "L", "A", "O"
                Case "O7 URS"
                    ProcessSheet ws, status, remainingDays, expDate, foundRows, "P,U", "O,T", "M,R", "A", "U"
                Case "O8 SZR"
                    ProcessSheet ws, status, remainingDays, expDate, foundRows, "I", "H", "F", "A", "I"
            End Select
        Next ws
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    
    If foundRows <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Pronađeni redovi:" & vbCrLf & foundRows
    Else
        MsgBox "Nema pronađenih redova za zadate parametre."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessSheet(ws As Worksheet, status As String, nrDays As Integer, expDate As Date, ByRef foundRows As String, _
                         ByVal statusColumns As String, ByVal remainingDaysColumns As String, ByVal expiryDateColumns As String, _
                         ByVal startColumn As String, ByVal endColumn As String)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim statusArray() As String
    Dim remainingDaysArray() As String
    Dim expiryDateArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    statusArray = Split(statusColumns, ",")
    remainingDaysArray = Split(remainingDaysColumns, ",")
    expiryDateArray = Split(expiryDateColumns, ",")
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, statusArray(0)).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRange = ws.Range(startColumn & "8:" & endColumn & lastRow)
    
    For Each cell In dataRange
        For i = LBound(statusArray) To UBound(statusArray)
            If status = "BOTH" Or cell.Offset(0, statusArray(i)).Value = status Then
                If (status = "<15 DANA" And cell.Offset(0, remainingDaysArray(i)).Value <= brojDana) Or _
                   (status = "<30 DANA" And cell.Offset(0, remainingDaysArray(i)).Value <= brojDana) Or _
                   (expDate <> "" And cell.Offset(0, expiryDateArray(i)).Value <= datumIsteka) Then
                    foundRows = foundRows & "Fajl: " & ws.Parent.Name & ", List: " & ws.Name & ", Red: " & cell.Row & vbCrLf
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next cell
End Sub

Function FileExists(filePath As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = Dir(filePath) <> ""
End Function

Private Sub Kalendar_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal DragState As MSForms.fmDragState, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub Kalendar_Click()
    Call Calendar.selectedDate(Me.txtDatum)
End Sub

Private Sub txtDatumPer_Click()
    Calendar.selectedDate Me.txtDatumPer
End Sub

Private Sub txtDatumPer_Enter()
    Calendar.selectedDate Me.txtDatumPer
End Sub


I think you should use Power Query for extracting files content based on a folder (especially if you need ChatGPT for the VBA code).
And you can import named cells in Power Query so that you can pass parameters from Excel to Power Query.
